# Triangles and Circles: A Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

I'm not able to solve the above problem. Please have a look at my attempt at the solution, where I'm stuck - also, your methods to solve the problem are welcome and you're requested to post them in the answers section.

For starters, here's what I did -

I constructed the incircle of ∆ABC, and named its intersection points with the circle as A', B' and C'. Clearly, AC' = AB'. 
Also, I noticed that the centre of the bigger circle, I, is collinear with D and G as the angle subtended at A is 90°. 
The inradius can be found easily (it's 15), by using Pythagoras Theorem to find the third side and using the well known result ∆ = rs, where ∆ is the triangle's area, r is its inradius and s is its semiperimeter.

Now, how should I proceed? Could someone please point me in the right direction, or provide a solution to the problem (which would probably help me understand the problem better)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a=\sqrt{55^2+48^2}=73.$$
Thus, $$r=\frac{55+48-73}{2}=15$$ and since $$\measuredangle BAI=45^{\circ},$$ we obtain $$AD=2r=30.$$
Similarly, $$AG=EF=30,$$ which gives that $DAFE$ is trapezoid and since
$$\measuredangle DEG=\measuredangle DAG=90^{\circ},$$
we obtain $EG\perp AF$.

Similarly, $DF\perp AE$, which says $AH\perp EF$ and since $\measuredangle EAF=45^{\circ},$ we obtain:
$$AH=EF\cot\measuredangle EAF=30\cot45^{\circ}=30.$$ 
By the way, there is a proof that $AH=EF$ without trigonometry.

Comment: How does the fact that angle BAI = 45° imply AD = 2r? What property have you used here?

Comment: @schrodinger_16 $I$ is incenter, which says that $AI$ is a bisector of $\angle BAC$.

Comment: I got that! I'm wondering why AD = 2r?

Comment: Because $DI=AI=r\sqrt2$.

Comment: Great. Understood it. Still can't figure out how to show AH = EF without trigonometry though..

Comment: Also, I think there's a slight correction necessary - AG = 30 not AC.

Comment: Yes of course. It was typo.

Comment: The hint: Let $EKAH$ be parallelogram and prove that $K$ placed on the given circle.